# Flutter Firebase OTP not working in Play store version

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-play-console

This my First Flutter app for Play Store.

the firebase OTP working fine on both debug and relse mode. but i upload the app on Play store the the play store version app OTP verification get failed it's retrun exception. i have add the SHA256 key from playstore.Please help me to solve this.

#attachment

!)firebase OTP screenshot marked as one for Playstore verstion and other one debug version
[OTP Screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4NYwu.jpg)
!!)Exception get after entering the OTP on PlayStore verstion
[Exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bILwN.jpg)